# What does it mean to demonstrate "por doble inclusión" in Spanish?

Tags: translation-request, mathematical-spanish

What does it mean to demonstrate "*por doble inclusión*" in Spanish? "By double-counting?" And what is that? thanks

For context, see, e.g., [this](https://es.answers.yahoo.com/question/index;_ylt=AwrTcdYlGctTxUQAPVNjmolQ;_ylu=X3oDMTByaDNhc2JxBHNlYwNzcgRwb3MDMQRjb2xvA2dxMQR2dGlkAw--?qid=20120509021306AAuAfCD).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know Spanish, but based on similarities with Portuguese I'd say it means "by double inclusion". I infer it's a problem that you need to prove $A = B$ where $A,B$ are sets. Therefore you prove $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$.

Comment: So, "by double inclusion" is a proper mathematical phrase in English?

Comment: @Geremia I believe so. You can always be explicit and say "we prove $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$..."

Answer (score 4):

When you want to prove an equality of two sets, say $X=Y$, you prove $X\subseteq Y$ and $Y\subseteq X$. Thatś what it means.

Comment: Second equation means probably $Y \subseteq X$. =)

Comment: If you want to be fancy, you can also say «probar por inclusión mutua»...

Comment: When you say "two sets" you mean "two subsets of a set"...

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, nope.

Comment: (Two sets are always subsets of a set, their union :-) )

Comment: :( ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, I don't know what you were hinting at, really.

Comment: "Inclusion" and "union" shouldn't take as input two sets; they should take as input two subsets of a set. For example, the question of whether $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3 - 2)$ is a subset of $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3 - 3)$, or of what their union is, is meaningless; you need to pick an embedding of these two fields into, say, $\mathbb{C}$ to make this question meaningful, and the answer depends on the choice of such an embedding.

Comment: I am sorry, Qiaochu, but that complaint is simply absurd in this context. Two sets are equal if they have the same elements, and this happens iff each contains the other.